# What is the best way to notify specified recipients by Stage after Azure DevOps deployments

Tags: notifications, azure-devops

We have 7 stages that we deploy to and I would like to notify different groups of people, all users on the project, when deployments succeed.

For instance, when:

- deployed to QA - notify the QA manager and team members, and when
- deployed to BETA - notify our product management group, and when
- deployed to PROD - notify etc

We have only one "Team" in the project (the default development team of 5 members) and the other users (another 6) are added to the Contributors group individually.

I can setup a notification subscription with the correct criteria for deployments to each stage, but can only set the delivery options to Team members, which in this case would exclude a lot of the intended recipients.  The other option is to use a custom email address, but then requires me to setup a distribution group outside of DevOps.

Should I create Teams for every distribution list?  This feels a bit cumbersome.  What are we doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at a Team is an e-mail distribution list within Azure DevOps, so Teams are the way to go.

Create a new Team in Dev Ops: `Project Settings > Teams > New Team`.  Then set up different notifcations for each Team: `Project Settings > Notifications > <name of team> > New Subscription`.

Comment: Thanks, that's my backup plan.  It just feels like a "team" is much more than an email group and I was hoping for a more light weight solution